# Action Hook For When A Custom PageLine's Section Is Updated in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook, pagelines

I am attempting to write a custom function to send the header and footer areas of the the pages to a .net web service anytime the content of the header or footer area is updated.  I have worked out the WordPress action hook for when the menus are updated,
`add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', 'write_html' );`
, but I need to also call my function when the header or footer sections are updated via pagelines.  We have custom sections that are being used for the header and footer areas.

I have looked through the Action hooks here:  http://api.pagelines.com/hooks 
and watched the hook tutorial here: http://www.pagelines.com/docs/base-child-theme

The video is talking more about Filters than Actions (using WordPress terminology) and the list of Actions in the api page doesn't show anything that might relate to updating a specific section.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a pre-exisiting Action hook for when a custom section's site wide settings are updated such as through PageLines > Page Options and selecting the section?
2. If not, how can a custom Action hook be added to a section's update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, found the right hook. Since it was working when menus were updated with `add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', 'write_html' );` all that was needed was a hook for when PageLines > Page Options were updated. The proper hook for that turns out to be `add_action( 'update_option_pagelines-special', 'write_html' );`